# chmod not work with virtualbox share folder

Tags: linux, docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, docker-machine

I have install docker-machine on virtuelbox . I mount share folder with

> mount -t vboxsf www /var/www

when i try to change permission file and my mount folder `chmod -Rf 777 namefile` not work.

i try to add my username to group vboxsf to 
my `/etc/group` like this

```
root:x:0:
lp:x:7:lp
nogroup:x:65534:
staff:x:50:docker
docker:x:100:docker
dockremap:x:101:dockremap
vboxsf:x:999:docker
vboxsf:x:999:docker@default
```

my docker vm is stoke is the docker default without images installed

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change permission of file in your mounted vboxsf folder using `chmod`.

The permission is controlled somewhere within virtuelbox sharing that I never bothered looked into, and that never bothers me. Why do you need to change permissions of your files for the first place?